# Flask app doesn't recognize flask_restful resources

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to build an API with flask_restful, but I don't know how to connect classes that inherit from Resource, with the actual app.
I have the following structure

```
  page
    ├───api
    │   └───__init__.py
    │   └───resources.py          
    └───__init__.py
```

page/api/resources.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from page import api


@api.resource("/hello-world")
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"hello": "World"}
```

page/**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from page.config import Config1

api = Api()

def create_app(config_class=Config1):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    api.init_app(app)

    return app
```

run.py (outside of the page package):

```
from page import create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

test:

```
import requests

BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.get(BASE + "hello-world")
print(response.json())
```

Obviously, making a request to "/hello-world" doesn't work. How can I "make Flask aware" of the resources, so that I get a valid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is a much clever way of doing this but for me, the solution would be to remove the decorator `@api.resource` decorator at `page/api/resources.py` and make the following changes at `page/init.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from page.config import Config1

def create_app(config_class=Config1):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    return app
```

I would also move the `run.py` inside the `page` folder and rename it to `app.py` according to Flask documentation. This `app.py` should have your routes so change it to something like this:

```
from page import create_app
from page.api.resources import HelloWorld
from flask_restfull import api

app = create_app()
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/hello-world')
```

And to run it just type `flask run` inside the `page` folder.

Comment: Yep. This is better.

Comment: It's okay but it fails the test in the question. It returns a 404 Response object

Comment: Adding to this answer, removing api = Api() and api.init_app(app), and changing it with api = Api(app) within the create_app function has solved the problem.